# Hover not working on vertical lines on Chart.js in angular app

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

We're using chart.js in our angular app to create a line graph with two datasets. The chart is displaying correctly.

I'm having trouble with the hover functionality which displays the tooltip. Currently, the tooltip only displays when I hover over a point (see image). What I want is for the tooltip to appear when I hover over a vertical line, instead of just a point.

My understanding is that this should be the default functionality. For me, it doesn't seem to be working.

I tried adding the hover key with the label mode, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Chart.js hover documentation: 
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-hover-configuration

```js
$scope.visitChartOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: true
  },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      title: (value) => {
        return moment(value[0].xLabel).format('LL');
      }
    }
  },
  hover: {
    mode: 'label'
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYNR9.png)